# LaTeX multi-character subscript

Tags: subscripts

I am including a formula in a LaTeX document that includes subscript that consists of more than one character: N sub t0 and N sub tmax

I managed to get LaTeX to do this using this syntax:

```
\[
  \vec{V} = \vec{N_t_0} * M \cdots \vec{N_t_m_a_x} * M
\]
```

This syntax throws multiple Double subscript errors.

Although it produced the intended results despite these errors, eventually these errors cause weird behaviors in the document, such as the bibliography dropping references, etc.  What is the correct syntax to produce the result I need without throwing errors?

Comment: note that even for a single character the official syntax would be `N_{t}` so multiple characters just go in the argument group in the same way: `N_{t_{0}}`

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to have multiple entries in a single subscript (or superscript), you need to group them using `{`...`}`. Below is an update to your equation, with appropriate use of `\vec` and other elements:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \vec{V} = \vec{N}_{t_0} \times M \cdots \vec{N}_{t_{\mathrm{max}}} \times M
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This absolutely fixed the problem and in retrospect enclosing the entire string in braces makes complete sense.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it recommended to use `mathit` instead of `mathrm`?

Comment: @alper: `max` is often used as a function, just like `\sin` and `\cos`, which are set in `rm`.

Comment: @Werner Ah thanks I understand it now. Assume I define my own function like `$require(x)$` on a table to define its meanining, should I use  `mathrm` as well for it?

Comment: @alper: It depends on the style your using, but sure. Define something like `\newcommand{\function}{\mathrm}` and then `\newcommand{\require}[1]{\function{require}(#1)}`.